# On Taylor series for two variable functions.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I know what Taylor series in one variable is. I was taught that in my calculus class as an application of derivatives. Now I saw somewhere these Taylor series of two variable. I tried to find a proof and detailed explanation of it but failed to get as I wanted. So I want a detailed explanation of two variable Taylor series and also a proof of it which I want to be intuitive.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with [tag:elementary-number-theory]?

Comment: See my answer to [What is a good way to teach Taylor expansion of multi-variable calculus?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/18733/745) for a heuristic way of developing and understanding multivariable Taylor series expansions and some possibly interesting problems involving their use.

Comment: José Carlos Santos, It went unfortunately I wanted to keep it only for those three.